# firebase functions error: grpc_node.node was compiled against a different Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I just downloaded and installed a newer node v8.9.4.

Then, I try to run firebase functions locally with command:

`firebase serve --only functions --debug`

I get the following node js version error:

```
functions: Cannot start emulator. Error: The module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

How can I get rid of this error (I would like to use latest node version)

**==== UPDATE ====**

I tried both `npm rebuild` and `npm install`, after that, I run `firebase serve --only functions --debug` again, but I still get the same error.

**===== UPDATE 2 =====**

I tried delete the module it complains about by:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/
```

Then, run:

```
npm install grpc
```

Then, run `firebase serve --only functions --debug` again, now I get error:

```
⚠  functions: Cannot start emulator. Error: Cannot find module 'grpc'
```

Seems it doesn't do what I wished, what should I do now to get rid of this new error???

Comment: _for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`_

Comment: Did do what the message suggested?  `npm rebuild` or `npm install`

Comment: I did `npm rebuild`, I still get the same error. Please see my update above.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by `sudo npm install -g grpc --allow-root --unsafe`

Comment: `yarn global add grpc` did the trick for me in combination with `Node 9.4.0`.

Comment: I have the same issue. It didn't help me